# Kivy Crashes when Loading Multiple Audio Files

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, ffmpeg, kivy

I have a *music* folder and in it I have a script that loads all the files using `SoundLoader` and assigns them to a variable. I have 9 audio files that I load in the script but it seems like that kivy cannot handle loading many audio files? When I run my main script I get this error and the program crashes:

```
Assertion 'pa_atomic_load(&(c)->_ref) >= 1' failed at pulse/context.c:1056, function pa_context_disconnect(). Aborting.
```

I don't think that this is an issue with the audio files ( I may be wrong ) because I tried loading other files instead of the original ones that I used and I still got this error.

In case you are wondering, this is the code:

```
import os.path
from typing import Final
from constants import MUSIC_DIRECTORY
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

__all__ = (
    "A_DARK_TIME",
    "BLOOD_PUMPING",
    "BROKEN_VILLAGE",
    "DRUM_COMMERCIAL_B",
    "SUPER_SUSPENSE",
    "THE_HERO_WE_NEED",
    "TROUBLE_IS_BREWING",
    "VIKING_FEAST",
    "WARRIOR_GODS",
)


A_DARK_TIME: Final = SoundLoader.load(
    os.path.join(MUSIC_DIRECTORY, "A-Dark-Time-David-Fesliyan.mp3")
)
BLOOD_PUMPING: Final = SoundLoader.load(
    os.path.join(MUSIC_DIRECTORY, "Blood-Pumping-David-Fesliyan.mp3")
)
BROKEN_VILLAGE: Final = SoundLoader.load(
    os.path.join(MUSIC_DIRECTORY, "Broken-Village-David_Fesliyan.mp3")
)
DRUM_COMMERCIAL_B: Final = SoundLoader.load(
    os.path.join(MUSIC_DIRECTORY, "Drum-Commercial-B-David-Fesliyan.mp3")
)
SUPER_SUSPENSE: Final = SoundLoader.load(
    os.path.join(MUSIC_DIRECTORY, "Super-Suspense-David-Fesliyan.mp3")
)
THE_HERO_WE_NEED: Final = SoundLoader.load(
    os.path.join(MUSIC_DIRECTORY, "The-Hero-We-Need-Steve-Oxen.mp3")
)
TROUBLE_IS_BREWING: Final = SoundLoader.load(
    os.path.join(MUSIC_DIRECTORY, "Trouble-Is-Brewing-David-Fesliyan.mp3")
)
VIKING_FEAST: Final = SoundLoader.load(
    os.path.join(MUSIC_DIRECTORY, "Viking-Feast-David-Fesliyan.mp3")
)
WARRIOR_GODS: Final = SoundLoader.load(
    os.path.join(MUSIC_DIRECTORY, "Warrior-Gods-Steve-Oxen.mp3")
)
```